# php artisan serve vs. npm run dev - difference between both servers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I just started to learn more about Laravel and I am confused about servers. When I run 'php artisan serve' in my project's folder, I can access my web project via localhost:8000. When I run npm run dev I can access via localhost:5173 - but I am not directed to my web project's landing page but to the welcome page of Laravel Vite. For me running 'php artisan serve' is the right option. So, now to my question(s): Did I do some kind of misconfiguration when setting up the project? Where is the difference between those two servers? Thank you for your answers! Robert

Comment: Your backend app runs via `php artisan serve` and your frontend UI runs with `npm run dev`. You probably should be running both when developing the app. When your app is deployed it will be a whole different story on what needs to be done

Comment: Hi @apokryfos - thank you! I thought I was developping my frontend and my backend via php artisan serve. Now, I need to think about your hint. Thank you for that!"

Answer (score 0):

`Php artisan serve` - hosts your project on your local server. And '`npm run dev`' command complies vite and it will track and update frontend modifications without reload.